# How to make dry bulgur wheat?

Tags: wheat

I am fond of bulgur wheat and often cook it with lots of veggies and season it with fresh herbs. What turns me off is the stickiness. It turns out to be too sticky when completely cooked. I want to cook bulgur wheat but at the same time keep it moist and dry. Someone please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you refer to cooking Bulgur wheat, do you boil it in a pot of water? Admittedly the only thing I have ever done with Bulgur wheat was Tabbouleh, where you just reconstitute the dry Bulgur wheat by pouring boiling water on it and letting it soak that way until it softens and fluffs up real nice & golden with every grain separate from the others. I.e. not sticky or gluey.

One time, on bad advice, I bought "cracked wheat" which is, I gather now from Wikipedia, not the same, even though some people think the two are identical. On that occasion, my "Bulgur" wheat did soften but was grayish in color and the individual grains stuck together kind of like oatmeal.

Wikipedia says that Bulgur wheat has been parboiled already, so you wouldn't need to boil it a lot to cook it, but merely re-hydrate with just the right amount of boiling water. So ... if *possibly* you are using "cracked wheat" like I did, maybe this info can help with the stickiness problem.

Comment: and if that doesn't work for you, you could try the traditional way of making couscous -- steam in, but get in there to break up clumps as it's cooking.  Or spread it on a sheet and roast it after it's done cooking to help dry out the surface.  (might have to break up clumps with that, too)

Answer (score 1):

One trick I use when cooking rice is to fry it in a bit of oil or butter first before adding any liquid. This eliminates the stickiness issue. Perhaps try out this approach. Yeah, I know, oil means calories, but olive oil is nutritious!